# Deixar efeito mais suave e aleatório

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte efeito:

```css
.fundo
{ 
-webkit-filter: blur(1px);
-moz-filter: blur(1px);
-ms-filter: blur(1px);
-o-filter: blur(1px);
filter: blur(1px);
width:500px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
background: #fff url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-RTxvEA_h-QE/VL0rqFeJUOI/AAAAAAAAAFA/FnwV5m9cSM0/w1920-h1200/BingWallpaper-2015-01-18.jpg") 50% 50%;
animation: anima-fundo 20s ease 1s infinite alternate;
-webkit-animation: anima-fundo 20s ease 1s infinite alternate;
-moz-animation: anima-fundo 20s ease 1s infinite alternate;
transition: 8s all;
-webkit-transition: 8s all;
-moz-transition: 8s all; }

@keyframes anima-fundo {
   0%   { background-position: 50% 50% }
   25%  { background-position: 55% 55% }
   50%  { background-position: 60% 45% }
   75%  { background-position: 40% 30% }
   100% { background-position: 60% 40% }
}

@-webkit-keyframes anima-fundo {
   0%   { background-position: 50% 50% }
   25%  { background-position: 55% 55% }
   50%  { background-position: 60% 45% }
   75%  { background-position: 40% 30% }
   100% { background-position: 60% 40% }
}

@-moz-keyframes anima-fundo {
   0%   { background-position: 50% 50% }
   25%  { background-position: 55% 55% }
   50%  { background-position: 60% 45% }
   75%  { background-position: 40% 30% }
   100% { background-position: 60% 40% }
}
```

```html
<div class="fundo"></div>
```

Queria saber como deixo ele mais suave e aleatório, se vocês observarem, ele sempre está indo em uma diagonal igual, no quesito suavidade, notem que ele está meio 'quadradão' quando troca de direção é muito seco e quebra o legal do efeito..

Então, como deixar ele mais suave e aleatório? Já 'fuçei' em tudo aí mais não consegui ter progresso.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com o "blur", uma impressão de velocidade ao se movimentar?

Comment: `blur` é um efeito de desfoque, vou retirar ele do post, porque o problema dele era não funcionar em todos browsers (em alguns ficaram muito ruim), mas consegui consertar.

Comment: Eu sei o que é o blur, rsrs, minha dúvida era apenas como aplicá-lo, mas como vai tirá-lo...

Comment: ah sim kkk, seria apenas aplicar ele na div, mas já apliquei :p

Comment: Se minha resposta atendeu sua questao, marque ela como correta, por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se é isso que queria, a aleatoriedade consegui com o JQuery.

```js
setInterval(function(){
    var random1 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*(60-50))+50);
    var random2 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*(55-45))+45);
    $('.fundo').animate({
  
        'background-position-x': random1 + "%",
        'background-position-y': random2 + "%"
  
    },  2500)
}, 100)
```

```css
.fundo {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #fff url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-RTxvEA_h-QE/VL0rqFeJUOI/AAAAAAAAAFA/FnwV5m9cSM0/w1920-h1200/BingWallpaper-2015-01-18.jpg") 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fundo"></div>
```

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, e deixar do meu gosto, obrigado! :)

Comment: Editei a resposta deixando o efeito mais suave limitando o `random` de `60 a 50` e `55 a 45` , mudando o tempo da animação e eliminando as linhas da animação do `css`.

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo utilizando o blur como você descreveu.

```
var timer1;
$(document).ready(function(){



    timer1 = setInterval(function(){
        var rnd1 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1);
        var rnd2 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1);

        //Aplica o blur na imagem
        $('.fundo').css("-webkit-filter", "blur(2px)");

        //Anima imagem
        $('.fundo').animate({
          'background-position-x': rnd1 + "%",
          'background-position-y': rnd2 + "%"
        },1500);

        //Verifica o termino da animacao com promisse().
        $('.fundo').promise().done(function() {
            $('.fundo').css("-webkit-filter", "blur(0px)");
        });

     },2000);

});
```

Você pode ver esse exemplo funcionando [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/yg29sqq7/).
Estou aplicando o blur no comeco da animacao e tiro o blur utilizando [.promisse()](https://api.jquery.com/promise/).